# MathType and Word Automation Programmatically

Tags: ms-word, mathtype

Is there a way to extract MathJax Tex (using MathType) programmatically from documents?
I can only extract it through manually running the conversion over the whole document.  It would be more convenient to be able to run it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a simple AutoIt script to make it more automatic.

In my case, manual labor was still opted for, and for some reason the choice was made to manually process the data into a certain form that the team at the time had chosen.  So making it fully automatic and programmatic ended up not being necessary.